# jq remove spaces after first

Tags: regex, jq

Seemed simple, but not so far. Tried lots of things. Best I've got:

```
echo "low quality      not gonna apologize" | jq -r 'gsub("[\\s+]"; " "; "g")'

parse error: Invalid numeric literal at line 1, column 4
```

Goal is to have 1 space replace any occurrence of multiple whitespace of any kind. Note that I removed tabs and newlines already from this stream.  This is bash shell. I don't get this error in the context of the larger application I'm building either, where the code is simply and quietly not changing the multiple spaces into a single space for IDK why.

Comment: The plus quantifier should be outside of the bracket expression, use `"\\s+"`

Comment: echo "low quality      not gonna apologize" | jq -r 'gsub("[\\s]+"; " "; "g")'
parse error: Invalid numeric literal at line 1, column 4

Comment: echo "low quality      not gonna apologize" | jq -r 'gsub("\\s+"; " "; "g")'
parse error: Invalid numeric literal at line 1, column 4

Comment: `("[\\s+]"; " "; "g")` is odd delimiter syntax. Sure you want to use this bizarre utility ?

Answer (score 6):

The right way with `jq`:

```
echo "low quality      not gonna apologize" | jq -Rr 'gsub("\\s+";" ";"g")'
```

- `-R` - *raw input*; each line of text is passed to the filter as a string

The output:

```
low quality not gonna apologize
```

Comment: With my quesiton at a -1 I can't bring mystelf to upvote or accept answer yet.  I would be happy to share credit however if you can upvote my question. Thanks.  I am being trolled I guess.

Comment: @GeoffreyAnderson, I did not downvote, but if you ask me to make you a gift with an upvote - you got my upvote. But that won't safe you from downvotes in future

Answer (score 0):

Two of many alternatives:

```
$ echo '"low quality      not gonna apologize"' | jq -r 'gsub("\\s+"; " ")'
low quality not gonna apologize

$ jq -n --arg in "low quality      not gonna apologize" '$in | gsub("\\s+"; " ")'
"low quality not gonna apologize"
```

Notice that:

- Not every shell string is a JSON string.
- The `--arg` command-line option has the effect of coercing the shell string to a JSON string.
- if you use 'gsub', there is no need to specify "g" as well.